# SwingWorker not working when I create a jar file

Tags: java, swing, jar, noclassdeffounderror, swingworker

I have the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
public class KaraokeMachine extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
ClassLoader Idr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
java.applet.AudioClip everythingIsAwesome = JApplet.newAudioClip( Idr.getResource( "everything is awesome.wav" ) );
JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel( "" );
JButton btn = new JButton( "Play" );
JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
final Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public KaraokeMachine()
{
    super( "Karaoke" );
    setSize( 520, 280 );
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    pnl.add( lbl1 );
    pnl.add( btn );
    btn.addActionListener( this );
    add( pnl ); setVisible( true );
}

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
{
    if ( event.getSource() == btn )
    {
            SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>()
            {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
                {
                    everythingIsAwesome.play();
                    this.publish("Everything");
                    Thread.sleep( 600 );
                    this.publish("Everything is");
                    Thread.sleep( 400 );
                    this.publish("Everything is Awesome!");
                    Thread.sleep( 2000 );
                    this.publish("Everything");
                    Thread.sleep( 600 );
                    this.publish("Everything is");
                    Thread.sleep( 400 );
                    this.publish("Everything is cool");
                    Thread.sleep( 400 );
                    this.publish("Everything is cool when");
                    Thread.sleep( 400 );
                    this.publish("Everything is cool when you're");
                    Thread.sleep( 400 );
                    this.publish("Everything is cool when you're part");
                    Thread.sleep( 150 );
                    this.publish("Everything is cool when you're part of");
                    Thread.sleep( 150 );
                    this.publish("Everything is cool when you're part of a");
                    Thread.sleep( 150 );
                    this.publish("Everything is cool when you're part of a team");
                    Thread.sleep( 1000 );
                    this.publish("Everything");
                    Thread.sleep( 600 );
                    this.publish("Everything is");
                    Thread.sleep( 400 );
                    this.publish("Everything is Awesome!");
                    Thread.sleep( 1500 );
                    this.publish("When");
                    Thread.sleep( 300 );
                    this.publish("When you're");
                    Thread.sleep( 300 );
                    this.publish("When you're livin'");
                    Thread.sleep( 300 );
                    this.publish("When you're livin' in");
                    Thread.sleep( 300 );
                    this.publish("When you're livin' in a");
                    Thread.sleep( 300 );
                    this.publish("When you're livin' in a dream!");
                    Thread.sleep( 300 );
                    return null;
                }
            @Override
            protected void process( List<String> res )
            {
                for(String text : res)
                {
                    lbl1.setText(text); 
                }
                }
        };
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
}
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    KaraokeMachine karaoke = new KaraokeMachine();
}
```

}

When I make this into a class file, it works fine but when I make it into a jar file, i get the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDegFoundError: KaraokeMachine$1

Does anyone know how to change the code so the swingworker works in a jar file?

Comment: Exception stack traces are **text**, too. Please do not screenshot them - add them as (formatted!) text to your question instead!

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll do that.

Comment: Better - but now you removed "too much". In this case it is ok, but, in general: it is ok to copy the "complete" stack trace into the question. An editor can always *remove* stuff that is not required - but he can't add what is missing.

Comment: I can't copy and paste out of command prompt though, but if it is ok in this case I'll leave it.

Comment: You should be able to. If this is windows - I think there is some preference setting somewhere that you change to allow copy/paste in the console. Alternatively, you should be able to **pipe** error messages into files. Like `someCommand 2> error.txt`

Comment: ok. I managed to create the jar file btw. It's working now- thanks for your help!

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept ;-)

Comment: Yep. Done. :) Thank you

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That exception means that some **anoymous inner class** is missing in your class path. So the answer is most likely: when you "bundle" your classes into that class file, you **forgot** that classes can be named `A$1.class`.

KaraokeMachine.class is the "main" class, but here:

```
SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
```

you are creating an anonymous inner class - which goes into KaraokeMachine$1.class. In order to run your application, you need **all** these class files to exist.

In other words: the content of your JAR file is incomplete. Have a close look at how you *build* that JAR file. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html) for example.

Comment: The contents of my jar file is:
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
KaraokeMachine.class
everything is awesome.wav
Is something missing out of that?

Comment: Oh look. It is empty. Surprise. Seriously: you are lacking **basic** knowledge; and at the same time, you try to learn various things at once. Like doing Java UI programming with swing, and then using JAR files. My 2 cent here: step back. Read tutorials covering the real **basics**. Dont go for "trial and error" when you dont have any experience in that area ... See my updated answer on help on using JARs btw.

Comment: Ok I'll have a look at the real basics.

Comment: Ok. Sure thing.